# pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, pg-dump, pg-restore

I have a live server and development box, call them live and dev respectively both running postgresql. I can see both and manage both with pgadmin4 without trouble, and both are fully functional the one being a live website and the other where I run my website in debug mode on the my dev box. Pretty ordinary setup.

For years I have been running the same bash script I wrote that dumps the live database then restores it on the dev box so I have the latest live snapshot to work with.

Today this fails me with the titled message:

```
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header
```

I have tried to diagnose this, and searched extensively on-line but am bedeviled and have failed so here I am cap in hand for expertise.

To help I will share the following:

```
$ pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 10.11 (Ubuntu 10.11-1.pgdg18.04+1)
$ pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 10.11 (Ubuntu 10.11-1.pgdg18.04+1)
$ pg_dump --host=live.lan --port=5432 --dbname=mydb --username=myuser --format=custom > test.backup
$ ls -l test.backup 
-rw-r--r-- 1 bernd bernd 2398358 Dec 23 23:40 test.backup
$ file test.backup 
test.backup: PostgreSQL custom database dump - v1.14-0
$ pg_restore --dbname=mydb test.backup 
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header
```

Given pg_dump and pg_restore are identical versions and:

```
$ which pg_dump
/usr/bin/pg_dump
$ which pg_restore
/usr/bin/pg_restore
$ ls -l /usr/bin/pg_dump /usr/bin/pg_restore
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Nov 14 23:23 /usr/bin/pg_dump -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 37 Nov 14 23:23 /usr/bin/pg_restore -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
```

I can see they are not just identical versions but are run by the same wrapper script (which happens to be a perl script - now that's a language you don't see much anymore and I used to code in extensively)

So I'm left totally perplexed. Thinking there may be a version issue with the live machine:

```
$ ssh live.lan
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-72-generic x86_64)
$ which pg_dump
/usr/bin/pg_dump
$ which pg_restore
/usr/bin/pg_restore
$ pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
$ pg_restore --version
pg_restore (PostgreSQL) 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
```

I can see the live box does have slightly older version of pg_dump (which would only matter if pg_dump on my dev box somehow used a RPC to the live box to run its pg_dump).

Now there is maybe a small clue in the fact that my dev box has seen a few postgresql upgrades come through and so for example:

```
$ pg_lsclusters
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory              Log file
10  main    5432 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
11  main    5433 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/11/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-11-main.log
12  main    5434 online postgres /var/lib/postgresql/12/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-12-main.log
```

The 11 and 12 clusters remain unused as evidenced by empty log files. I'm using 10. But I do notice that:

```
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 12.1 (Ubuntu 12.1-1.pgdg18.04+1)
$ ssh live.lan
Welcome to Ubuntu 18.04.3 LTS (GNU/Linux 4.15.0-72-generic x86_64)
$ psql --version
psql (PostgreSQL) 10.10 (Ubuntu 10.10-0ubuntu0.18.04.1)
```

which is mildly fishy but again not obviously a cause or related:

1. I am using pg_dump not psql
2. I am using only the dev boxes pg tools not the live boxes (they should be irrelevant, the whole data transfer theoretically over port 5432 on the live box which delivers a databse dump to pg_dump on my dev box.

Here are the clusters on the love box and it's over port 5432 that on live.lan I'm running pg_dump!

```
$ pg_lsclusters 
Ver Cluster Port Status Owner    Data directory           Log file
10  main    5432 online postgres /data/postgresql/10/main /var/log/postgresql/postgresql-10-main.log
```

I am deeply perplexed and hamstrung at present by this. Would deeply appreciate forward moving clues. If I am compelled to fish around in the dark I will probbaly uninstall postgres 11 and 12 again and see if that helps, else I will end up having to trace `/usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper` to see how and where the two paths of pg_dump and pg_restore diverge down incompatible version paths.

**Update:**

A further clue I have uncovered, that permits me a workaround but simply deepens the mystery is as follows:

```
$ sudo -u postgres pg_dump --host=live.lan --port=5432 --dbname=mydb --username=myuser --format=custom > test.backup
$ sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_dump --host=live.lan --port=5432 --dbname=mydb --username=myuser --format=custom > test2.backup
$ sudo -u postgres pg_restore -l test.backup
pg_restore: [archiver] unsupported version (1.14) in file header
$ sudo -u postgres pg_restore -l test2.backup
... produces listing of contents ...
$ sudo -u postgres pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 10.11 (Ubuntu 10.11-1.pgdg18.04+1)
$ sudo -u postgres /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_dump --version
pg_dump (PostgreSQL) 10.11 (Ubuntu 10.11-1.pgdg18.04+1)
```

That is perplexing beyond belief. The only possible explanations:

1. in spite of reporting identical version numbers the two pg_dumps are different. I would rule this out as beyond belief.
2. pg_dump runs pg_wrapper which runs /usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_dump with some mystery argument(s) that break it!

The second is plausible, and will require me to instrument pg_wrapper to diagnose.

**Update 2:**

And one instrumentation of pg_wrapper later. It eventuates that pg_dump runs pg_wrapper which runs `/usr/lib/postgresql/12/bin/pg_dump` yet it runs `/usr/lib/postgresql/10/bin/pg_restore` ... Go figure! Starting to think this a postgresql version interoperability bug!

**Update 3:**

Looking deeper into `pg_wrapper`, nailed the cause, and yes I'd argue it's a pg_wrapper bug of a kind though it may be debatable, hardly though IMHO. Here's what it does:

If `--host` is provided then it uses the newest version of postgresql installed (12 in my case and this is for pg_dump, so pg_dump 12 creates the dump)

If `--host` is not provided then it consults the user config (10 in my case, and this is for pg_restore, so pg_restore 10 is run and it can't read a file created by pg_dump 12).

So why is this a bug? Because I have a use config, and I'd like it respected whether or not I'm talking to a remote host. More to the point if I specify a host I certainly don't expect to use the latest local version ignoring local config. I'd expect either to respect local config (as is the case when no remote host is specified) or try to match the rmeote hosts version. Arbitrarily leaning on the latest installed version is IMHO deeply questionable.

BUT it turns out there is a workaround that works. Essentially instead of:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_restore -l test.backup
```

this works:

```
sudo -u postgres pg_restore --host=localhost -l test.backup
```

By specifying the host ironically we force it to ignore local configs and use the newest version of pg_restore which seems to work fine restoring to a PG 10 cluster.

Comment: "Starting to think this a postgresql version interoperability bug!"  Sounds more like a packaging bug.

Comment: @BerndWechner I used the following command: `sudo -u postgres pg_restore --verbose --clean --jobs=4 --disable-triggers --no-acl --no-owner -h localhost -U postgresql -d everest_development dump.psql` but that didn't work. I am also getting same error while importing one database.

Comment: Also if I do: `muhammad@muhammad-mohsin:~/workspace_ror/everest$ psql -d everest_development -f dump.psql
The input is a PostgreSQL custom-format dump.
Use the pg_restore command-line client to restore this dump to a database.
`

Comment: I confirm your finding. pg_dump uses the latest (v12) executable if host is explicitly specified. This looks like a bug or design flaw.

Comment: what is the solution? I tried all of that scenarios

Comment: Not sure of a "solution" but I posted a workaround. The difference to my mind is that it works but shouldn't be needed, `pg_wrapper` should be smarter than it is. The workaround is simply to specify `--host explicitly` when using `pg_dump` and `pg_restore` and this forces them both to use the same version of postgresql (the latest one installed on your system) and remain compatible. If you use `--host` on one and not the other and have multiple versions of postgresql installed and an earlier version still in use in local configs, then forgetting this issue arises.

Comment: Just download the latest pg admin if you are using windows

Comment: Good grief what a hassle. Here I thought I was going to be able to WFH today but I guess I have a bunch of bull to wade through first before I can just do a pg:pull from Heroku.

Answer (score 18):

ubuntu guys: most likely your `pg_restore` is outdated. Just [use postgres doc](https://www.postgresql.org/download/linux/ubuntu/) and install newest version of postgres:

1. Create the file `/etc/apt/sources.list.d/pgdg.list` and add a line for the repository: `deb http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt/ YOUR_UBUNTU_VERSION_HERE-pgdg main` where ubuntu versions are:

   - 20.04 - focal
   - 18.04 - bionic
   - 16.04 - xenial
2. Add keys: `wget --quiet -O - https://www.postgresql.org/media/keys/ACCC4CF8.asc | sudo apt-key add -`
3. `sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade`

It worked for me!

Comment: E: The repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt bionic-pgdg Release' no longer has a Release file.

Comment: You'd think Postgres could make this a bit more clear instead of returning a nonsensical version number that's not used by any version of Postgres...

Answer (score 9):

So my experience here was somewhat similar to OP, but not completely.

I had versions 9.4, 9.5, 11, and 12 installed, and all the pg_* tools pointed to the 9.4 version. I tried to pg_restore a dump create by version 12 on a different host, which didn't work because this host used the 9.4 tools, which were incompatible (same error as OP posted).

So, here was my debugging flow:

- `which pg_restore`

  - /usr/bin/pg_restore
- `ls -l /usr/bin/pg_restore`

  - /usr/bin/pg_restore -> ../share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper
- `vim /usr/share/postgresql-common/pg_wrapper`

  - Read about how it determines version. Just read through the first 20 or so lines

Apparantly, there is a `--cluster` option, which is helpful in resolving the version. So I simply added `--cluster 12/main`to my `pg_restore` call, and everything works as expected again

Comment: The instructions at [https://render.com/docs/migrate-from-heroku](https://render.com/docs/migrate-from-heroku) didn't  work until I added the `--cluster` param. Adding `--cluster [version#]/main` to the `pg_restore` command helped me copy the `pg_dump` file created by Heroku to a Render.com Postgres service. The dump file was created with Postgres version 15. `pg_restore` on my AWS EC2 instance was locked at version 10.23 , even though *psql* was upgraded to version 15 (still trying to resolve this), so the Postgres service on Render.com was not reading the file because of the mismatch.

Comment: Adding the `--cluster` flag just generates the following error: `pg_restore: unrecognized option `--cluster'`

Comment: I was able to solve the pg_restore v10.23 issue by removing all installed PostgreSQL versions except v16 with "sudo apt remove postgresql-[old version]" + "sudo rm -rf /etc/postgresql/[old version]"

Answer (score 5):

Here's another twist, but please note first that this is a windows case.
If it's just linux for you, don't read further.
All advice given here did not help me, eventually the cause IMC was simpler and had to do with the use of pgAdmin. Because of the repetitive nag for newer versions, my habit is to install pgAdmin separately (not using stackbuilder).
(AT LEAST) in that case, pgAdmin has its own cache of utility programs and will use these unless you tell it differently. My pg instances are still version 11(.6), but the latest pgAdmin will probably have V12 utilities. Which may quite well cause a version discrepancy.
This crept up on me after doing a number of succesful transfers from my main machine to a laptop. So, in pgAdmin do (menu)File->preferences->Paths and set Binary Paths corresponding to your postgres installation, IMC C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\11\bin.
That did the job.

Answer (score 2):

check and see if your pgadmin is up to date, I had this problem and resolved it by updating it

Answer (score 1):

> This error is caused by a version mismatch between the version of pg_dump used to create the backup file and the version of pg_restore used to attempt the restore.

Updating my PostgreSQL solved the problem

Comment: To what version? v12 clearly had this problem in pg_wrapper. What version did you upgrade to? If there's an update to 12 that fixes it, let us know.

Comment: I have upgraded to version 12.2

Answer (score 1):

On my case (on Mac, Postgres managed by Homebrew) the solution was to check the **pg_dump** version used to create the dump file and install that version of **postgresql**.

Apparently with Brew you can't install pg_restore separately from postgresql (not sure, didn't really dig into it), so I needed to install postgresql@12 and link it. That did it.

Answer (score 0):

My pg_restore have 11.21 version and my file to restore have this header. What is the version bak file 11.18 or 15.2?  Or its possible execute command to bak file to show this version pg_dump?
for download the same postgres version recommend this ftp postgres?

[image]

[image]